# Нет подключения к ssh по ключу ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Проблема невозможности создания подключения доступа к машине по ssh через ключ, возникла после того как сервер с настроенным соединением переустановил.
Сейчас произвожу на клиенте следующие действия:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pc-10@192.168.1.210/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/alexandr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
pc-10@192.168.1.210's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'pc-10@192.168.1.210'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

ssh pc-10@192.168.1.210
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
pc-10@192.168.1.210's password: 

ssh-keygen -t dsa
ssh pc-10@192.168.1.210
rm .ssh/authorized_keys
exit 
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pc-10@192.168.1.210 
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub pc-10@192.168.1.210
ssh pc-10@192.168.1.210 
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
раскоментировал: 
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Как можно увидеть соединение запрашивает пароль. Что мне нужно сделать. чтобы не нанести возможный вред клиентской машине и её настроенными ключами доступа к другим машинам?

Comment: удалить улюч и добавить новый ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/762541/416190

Comment: @SeniorAutomator обновил вопрос, чтобы было яснее

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на этот ресурс заходил, не помогло

Comment: Добрый день! попробуйте подключится указав путь к ключу полностью - ssh -i <path>/id_rsa pc-10@192.168.1.210

Comment: сообщение *agent refused operation* очевидно свидетельствует о том, что ssh-agent по какой-то причине неработоспособен. подключайтесь без него: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh pc-10@192.168.1.210` (это одна команда).

Comment: с этой командой вход был произведён по ключу шифрования (passphrase), после попробовал войти обычным методом, также запрашивает пароль